# Can I connect my Apex cloud workspace account with my remote oracle DB account?

Tags: cloud, apex

I have a free apex Workspace account.
Can I connect my Apex cloud workspace account with my remote oracle DB account ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes...You can connect thru DB link or restful services